# How to display a list of child elements on the show page?

Tags: react-admin

myAPI has 3 tables,

- Groups, 1group has many users(one-to-many)
- Users, 1user has many posts(one-to-many)
- Posts (no children)

In "/groups/:group_id/show", you can see the status of a group.
What I want to do is to have the show page show the details of the element and list the children that have that element as a parent.
If you click on one of the children in the list, it will display the details of the element and its children in the list as well. In other words, I want to embed the list in the show and create a nest structure.

I have completed the tutorial on React-admin.
In the tutorial, when I click on an item from the list view of Posts, the detailed information of that post is displayed. `/posts/posts_id/show`.
This page is rendered using `simpleShowLayout`, but if I want to do more list views on this page, what should I do?

In "/groups/", send a request to "api_endpoint/grops".
If I want to nest them
"groups/group_id/show" will send the request to "api_endpoint/groups/group_id".

I think I need to create the dataprovider and showlayout by myself, is that correct?
I don't know where to start, so could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your "SimpleShowLayout" for your Group, you will have to add a children of type "[ReferenceManyField](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencemanyfield)"

For ex:

```
<SimpleShowLayout {...props}>
    {/* Here you are in the show context of 1 Group *}
    <TextField source="name"/> {/* Name of the group *}
    <ReferenceManyField reference="Users" source="id" target="GroupId">
        {/* Here you are in the list context of Users, for all the users whose GroupId is equal to the id of the currently shown group *}
        ...
    </ReferenceManyField>
</SimpleShowLayout/>
```

Then, as told in the link, as children of the "ReferenceManyField" you can use a Datagrid to show all the users.

If you want to go further, in a column of the Datagrid you can put another ReferenceManyFields that shows all the Posts for the user.